# Elasticsearch. How to stem plurals ending in es?

Tags: elasticsearch

For the EN language I have a custom analyser using the porter_stem. I want queries with the words "virus" and "viruses" to return the same results.

What I am finding is that porter stems virus->viru and viruses->virus. Consequently I get differing results.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your use case, i.e,   **queries with the words "virus" and "viruses" should return the same result**, by using [snowball token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-snowball-tokenfilter.html),
that stems all the words to their root word.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_snow"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_snow": {
          "type": "snowball",
          "language": "English"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "desc": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Analyze API**

```
GET /_analyze

{
  "analyzer" : "my_analyzer",
  "text" : "viruses"
}
```

Following tokens are generated -

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "virus",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "desc":"viruses"
}
{
    "desc":"virus"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "desc": {
        "query": "viruses"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65707743",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "desc": "viruses"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65707743",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "desc": "virus"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks. How does one get to see the index data?

Comment: @BenderRodriguez do you want to see all the data that is indexed? For this, you can use the match all query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html

Comment: I want to see, for example, when it stems "virus" it gets "viru" - where does it store that word, and other words that have been stemmed. Thanks.